# SIGSEGV on llvm-link

Tags: crash, llvm

I am getting a segmentation fault on

```
llvm-link -S -o result.ll test.ll minimized.ll
```

Is this a bug or is something wrong with my inputs?

The files are:

test.ll

```
; ModuleID = 'test_opt2.ll'
source_filename = "test.ll"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

@.str = external global [5 x i8]

define i32 @basilisk_test() {
entry:
  %p602400_real = getelementptr [5 x i8], [5 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0
  ret i32 0
}
```

minimized.ll:

```
; ModuleID = 'minimized.ll'
source_filename = "llvm-link"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

@zSuffix = dso_local global [4 x i8*] [i8* getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i8], [5 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @.str.1, i32 0, i32 0), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([6 x i8], [6 x i8]* @.str.2, i32 0, i32 0), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i8], [5 x i8]* @.str.3, i32 0, i32 0)], align 16
@.str = weak unnamed_addr constant [5 x i8] c".bz2\00", align 1
@.str.1 = weak unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c".bz\00", align 1
@.str.2 = weak unnamed_addr constant [6 x i8] c".tbz2\00", align 1
@.str.3 = weak unnamed_addr constant [5 x i8] c".tbz\00", align 1
```

The stack is:

```
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: llvm-link-12 -S -o result.ll test.ll minimized.ll
Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1(_ZN4llvm3sys15PrintStackTraceERNS_11raw_ostreamEi+0x23)[0x7fe2ba12b683]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1(_ZN4llvm3sys17RunSignalHandlersEv+0x50)[0x7fe2ba1299c0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1(+0xcf2cef)[0x7fe2ba12bcef]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12980)[0x7fe2b922c980]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1(_ZN4llvm14GlobalVariable15eraseFromParentEv+0x1c)[0x7fe2ba2228fc]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1(+0x1c47b17)[0x7fe2bb080b17]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1(_ZN4llvm7IRMover4moveESt10unique_ptrINS_6ModuleESt14default_deleteIS2_EENS_8ArrayRefIPNS_11GlobalValueEEESt8functionIFvRS7_SA_IFvSB_EEEEb+0x9fb)[0x7fe2bb07f21b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-12.so.1(_ZN4llvm6Linker12linkInModuleESt10unique_ptrINS_6ModuleESt14default_deleteIS2_EEjSt8functionIFvRS2_RKNS_9StringSetINS_15MallocAllocatorEEEEE+0x1121)[0x7fe2bb088eb1]
llvm-link-12[0x4083b0]
llvm-link-12[0x405d49]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7fe2b850bbf7]
llvm-link-12[0x40573a]
```

I can't submit a bug report, because account creation is disabled in their bug tracker.

Comment: I don't have time to really look at it, but shouldn't that `getelementptr` return i8? Are you sure [that IR is valid](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Verifier_8h.html)?

Comment: Changing it to i8 or i8* leads to `error: explicit pointee type doesn't match operand's pointee type`, so I guess it is correct

Comment: Also, clang transforms both files to binary bitcode without any complaints. If I rename the function to `main`, it even generates a binary.